# How unserialize data which is serialized using maybe_serialize in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new in wordpress and I don't know the exact opposite process of maybe_serialize() function in it. The problem is that in my application there is one form 'user registration' and value stored in database of this form is like below (serialized using `$entries = maybe_serialize($entry);`):

`a:14:{s:9:"user_name";s:3:"adi";s:10:"user_email";s:13:"adi@gmail.com";s:9:"user_pass";s:7:"aaaaaaa";s:4:"role";s:10:"subscriber";s:11:"firstname_1";s:3:"adi";s:10:"lastname_2";s:3:"gad";s:13:"collegename_4";s:3:"hgh";s:15:"currentstatus_5";s:7:"Student";s:13:"passoutyear_7";s:4:"2012";s:8:"branch_8";s:2:"IT";s:6:"year_9";s:2:"SE";s:12:"contactno_10";s:10:"9934672345";s:7:"User_IP";s:3:"::1";s:7:"Browser";s:109:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36";}`

I want to print this record like 'user name = adi user_email=adi@gmail.com etc.' I know `unserialize($entries);` function but don't know how to use it.
How can I handle this. Please give any suggestion.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unserialize it by using php function unserialize($data) or wordpress function maybe_unserialize($data). Both will return you array data.